# Enable/Disable deleted answers visibility

Tags: feature-request

We currently have 13 users with 10k+ rep, and a few more to come. 10k+ users can see deleted answers. Sometimes this has its uses, but sometimes they're a nuisance, like when there are [8 deleted answers by the same user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmiC5.png) to a question.

**Feature-request**
Allow users to enable/disable this visibility in their profile. To be clear: not permanently disable; like I said it has its uses and then it must be "enable-able" again.

*(thanks Oli and Kortuk for the support.)*

Comment: I probably be like 237th 10k+ user, but I think it is a good option.

Comment: @jippie - Thanks. Only 8000 more to go! (BTW, When I look at your gravatar, you're really a pretty guy! LOL)

Comment: If you were wondering: Yes my ears are really hanging down ;o)

Comment: Sounds like something that can be done easily with a user script.

Comment: @ThiefMaster EE.SE site probably has the lowest use of userscripts.

Comment: Gets my vote, I sometimes get rather tired of seeing so many deleted spam posts, so it would be very nice to have option.

Comment: @Kortuk - what's a user script?

Comment: @OliGlaser A way to modify site behavior locally by installing things into your browser.

Comment: Where can we learn more about user scripts? (10k newbie speaking here)

Comment: @Madman - congrats on the 10k!

Comment: Been tough with all you senior guys snarfing the good questions ;)

Comment: I was about a factor 10 off in [my earlier comment](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/enable-disable-deleted-answers-visibility#comment3762_1411), but I still think it would be nice if deleted answers were at least **folded** or so.